# Order Wordpress Custom Taxonomy Pages & Pagination Not Working

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, pagination, taxonomy

I'm using this code to enable custom post types and taxonomies on my site (I've also included this below to save linking out)

https://gist.github.com/kasparsd/2924900

The code works great for the most part, however I'm having issues with 2 things:

1. I would like to order the posts on the archive pages using the title - at the moment it simply orders by date.
2. Using Pagination throws up a 404 error - and won't load the extra
   posts

I've tried a few different methods but I'm now stuck and not any closer

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

```html
<?php /*
Term Archive Pages:
 - http://example.com/recipes/dinner/
 - http://example.com/recipes/breakfast,brunch/
Single Recipe Pages:
 - http://example.com/recipes/dinner/soup-title/
 - http://example.com/recipes/breakfast,brunch/egg-dish-title/
*/
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_types' );
function register_my_types() {
    register_post_type( 'recipes',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Recipes' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Recipee' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'occasion', array( 'recipes' ), array( 
            'hierarchical' => true, 
            'label' => 'Occasions'
        )
    );
}
// Add our custom permastructures for custom taxonomy and post
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'add_clinic_permastructure' );
function add_clinic_permastructure() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_permastruct( 'occasion', 'recipes/%occasion%', false );
    add_permastruct( 'recipes', 'recipes/%occasion%/%recipes%', false );
}
// Make sure that all links on the site, include the related texonomy terms
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'recipe_permalinks', 10, 2 );
function recipe_permalinks( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'recipes' )
        return $permalink;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'occasion' );

    if ( ! $terms )
        return str_replace( '%occasion%/', '', $permalink );
    $post_terms = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term )
        $post_terms[] = $term->slug;
    return str_replace( '%occasion%', implode( ',', $post_terms ) , $permalink );
}
// Make sure that all term links include their parents in the permalinks
add_filter( 'term_link', 'add_term_parents_to_permalinks', 10, 2 );
function add_term_parents_to_permalinks( $permalink, $term ) {
    $term_parents = get_term_parents( $term );
    foreach ( $term_parents as $term_parent )
        $permlink = str_replace( $term->slug, $term_parent->slug . ',' . $term->slug, $permalink );
    return $permlink;
}
// Helper function to get all parents of a term
function get_term_parents( $term, &$parents = array() ) {
    $parent = get_term( $term->parent, $term->taxonomy );

    if ( is_wp_error( $parent ) )
        return $parents;

    $parents[] = $parent;
    if ( $parent->parent )
        get_term_parents( $parent, $parents );
    return $parents;
} ?>
```